How to solve $\int \frac{2020x^{2019}+2019x^{2018}+2018x^{2017}}{x^{4044}+2x^{4043}+3x^{4042}+2x^{4041}+x^{4040}+1}dx$
One of my friends sent me a list of integrals (all without solutions )  one of those problems is: $$\int \frac{2020x^{2019}+2019x^{2018}+2018x^{2017}}{x^{4044}+2x^{4043}+3x^{4042}+2x^{4041}+x^{4040}+1}dx$$
the numerator is $\frac{d}{dx}x^{2018}(1+x+x^2)$ and the denominator is $\left(x^2\left(x^{2018}(1+x+x^2)\right)\right)^2 +1$  so unless I am mistaken this integral is in the form of  $\int\frac{f'(x)}{1+(x^2f(x))^2}dx$ which I don't know how to solve, maybe (If this problem is unsolvable ) there is a typo,  but I couldn't verify that whether this problem has a typo or not since wolfram alpha for some reason don't understand my input.

Since this question seems to be incorrect I wounder what is the result of   $\int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{2020x^{2019}+2019x^{2018}+2018x^{2017}}{x^{4044}+2x^{4043}+3x^{4042}+2x^{4041}+x^{4040}+1}dx$ Does this have a nice closed form
?

only take $f(x)=x$,the answer is very complicated.

Maybe the problem was about $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ and maybe it was in a problem list on complex analyses?

@SergeiNikolaev This was the question number 24 on this list and none of the previous 23 problems involved complex analysis or special functions

@pie Were the previous problems about definite or about indefinite integrals?

This antiderivative is both elementary and non elementary at the same time in that it is the sum of elementary functions, but the sum is indexed over the roots of a transcendental equation. It is a living monstrosity of a counterexample that closed form is not beauty.

@SergeiNikolaev 17 of 23 were indefinite

@NinadMunshi Now I am very curious to see that solution

I suspect the problem's author wanted a solution of the form $\arctan[x^n(x^2+x+1)]+C$ but accidentally used one value of $n$ in the integrand's numerator with another in its denominator.

As suggested in the comments by @Ninad Munshi, if we let $f(x)=x^{n}(1+x+x^2)$, putting $n=0$ (the trivial case) allows partial fraction decomposition of the integrand into:
$$
\frac{1}{13}\frac{4x+7}{(x^2+1)} - \frac{1}{13} \frac{4x^5+15x^4+18x^3-x^2-22x-6}{x^6+2x^5+2x^4-x^2+1} = \frac{1}{13}\frac{4x+7}{(x^2+1)} - \frac{1}{13} \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}
$$
WolframAlpha solves it to:
$$\frac{1}{13}\left(7\tan^{-1} (x) +2\ln(1+x^2) -\sum_{\omega_j: Q(\omega_j)=0 } \frac{P(\omega_j)}{Q'(\omega_j)}\ln (x-\omega_j) \right)$$ The interesting thing is that similar-looking solutions are there for the general case of $n≠0$. Only the coefficient of the $\arctan x$ term increases, and the polynomials $P$ and $Q$ grow in order.
